# All sata disks are 6.0 Gbps, but some hdd are running slower than others, why?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sata

I just setup a server with 10 same model hard disks. They are connected to the huananzhi X99-AD3 motherboard ([https://www.amazon.com/HELLOLAND-HUANANZHI-Motherboard-Supported-Supports/dp/B082W24TBR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082W24TBR)). `dmesg | grep SATA` shows they are all in 6.0Gbps mode.

```
[manjaro bht]# dmesg | grep SATA
[    4.868372] ahci 0000:00:11.4: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 4 ports 6 Gbps 0xf impl SATA mode
[    4.897174] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb419000 port 0xfb419100 irq 33
[    4.897176] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb419000 port 0xfb419180 irq 33
[    4.897177] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb419000 port 0xfb419200 irq 33
[    4.897179] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb419000 port 0xfb419280 irq 33
[    4.897410] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 6 ports 6 Gbps 0x3f impl SATA mode
[    4.947537] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb416000 port 0xfb416100 irq 34
[    4.947538] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb416000 port 0xfb416180 irq 34
[    4.947540] ata7: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb416000 port 0xfb416200 irq 34
[    4.947541] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb416000 port 0xfb416280 irq 34
[    4.947542] ata9: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb416000 port 0xfb416300 irq 34
[    4.947544] ata10: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xfb416000 port 0xfb416380 irq 34
[    5.210474] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.210497] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.210519] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.210538] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.260458] ata10: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.260478] ata9: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.260498] ata8: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.260518] ata7: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.260537] ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[    5.260554] ata6: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
```

I'm running multiple badblocks tests with bht(https://github.com/ezonakiusagi/bht) on these drives, I noticed that four of the hdds are slower than the other six ones. Note that the while time elapsed are the same, four disks' progress are much less than the other six.

```
[manjaro bht]# ./bht --status
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_X1G6H9LL:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing  54.27% done, 31:15:19 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=1]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_QGGDS91T:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing  56.07% done, 31:15:19 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=1]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_XHG0J1MD:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing  54.20% done, 31:15:20 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=1]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_QGG3AB2T:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing  54.56% done, 31:15:20 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=1]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_QGH5V04T:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing  53.53% done, 31:15:20 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=1]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_QGGE07HT:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing  57.00% done, 31:15:21 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=1]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_X1G502KL:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing   4.50% done, 31:15:21 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=0]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_X1G9TYHL:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing   3.96% done, 31:15:22 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=0]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_QGGL1ZVT:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing   5.29% done, 31:15:22 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=1]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
WDCWD120EMFZ-11A6JA0_XHG0VRYD:
        badblocks[Reading and comparing   4.00% done, 31:15:22 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)]
        HDD Type:[SATA]
        SMART:[Reallocated_Sector_Ct=0]
        SMART:[Power_On_Hours=1]
        SMART:[Multi_Zone_Error_Rate=0]
```

I noticed in dmesg output, four disks are connected to `0000:00:11.4` while the other six are connected to `0000:00:1f.2`. lspci shows this:

```
00:11.4 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset sSATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset 6-Port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
```

It shows one is called `sSATA Controller` and the other is called `6-Port SATA Controller`. What's the difference? I'm still wondering what's the root reason that the four drives are much slower? Cloud I fix it?

Here is the full output of `lspci -vvv` https://pastebin.com/R4TFwGq7 and `lspci -tv` https://pastebin.com/3w73uZK9

Comment: All 10 SATA cables are identical?

Comment: @Ramhound 8 of the 10 cables are identical. I will check whether later whether all of them can reach 6.0 Gbps speed.

Comment: My guess is these four disks are probably on a [secondary SATA controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/829176/what-is-a-ssata-port) rather than chipset's built-in one. It's connected through a PCIe link that's too narrow for all disks to work with full performance. I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't know how to verify if that's indeed the case.

Comment: I'd have to agree with gronostaj here, it sounds like the 6 port controller is yet another bridge and the link to that bridge is starved of bandwidth. Do you have any other PCIe devices that might be sharing the PCIe bus and reducing the number of PCIe links such as graphics cards or PCIe network cards?

Comment: @Mokubai Yes I do have a graphics card and PCIe network card. Here is the full output of `lspci -vvv` https://pastebin.com/R4TFwGq7 and `lspci -tv` https://pastebin.com/3w73uZK9 How to find out how many lanes are for the sata controllers?

Comment: The 2nd SATA controller (on which you have the 4 slow drives) can be configured with a flexible number of PCIe lanes. This allows the motherboard maker to re-purpose some lanes for other purposes like a 2nd M.2 slot, a 2nd NIC or an extra USB controller. Without a detailed diagram of the exact setup used by your motherboard i can't tell how it is setup. Disabling not-used functions on the motherboard (like M.2 slots) may free those lanes.

Comment: @Nublia according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/394464/finding-pcie-lanes-in-linux) you might be able to run `lspci -vv` (double verbose) as root and look for `LnkSta`to find out how many lanes are in use.

Comment: @Mokubai Here https://pastebin.com/SKNnQ05J is the output of `lspci -vv` but there is no `LnkSta` under the two SATA controller items.

Comment: @Tonny Do you mean detail diagram like [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.tweaktown.com%2Fcontent%2F7%2F8%2F7887_23_asus-x99-deluxe-ii-motherboard-review.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tweaktown.com%2Freviews%2F7887%2Fasus-x99-deluxe-ii-motherboard-review%2Findex.html&tbnid=zOrs1pVMc_vHiM&vet=1&docid=j-PKCuqbLcqDuM&w=620&h=627&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)? This motherboard maker does  not publish this kind of diagram, could we tell from the motherboard's photo?

Comment: @Nublia Yes, something like that. The only thing I can get from the motherboard photo on Amazon is that there are 2 M.2 slots, while the X99 chipset only has 1 on its own. That means the 2nd M.2 is probably taking PCIe lanes away from the SATA.